# Need to know how to display an NSMutableArray to a UITableView Xcode 5

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am currently trying to display a NSMutableArray into a UITableView. The problem lies in the NumberOfRowsInSection and in the CellForRowAtIndex. I am able to fetch twitter feed and logic to the console, but I can't seem to display it to my UITable view. What could be the reason?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>
#import "TwitterPostInfo.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    twitterPosts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self refreshTwitter];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)refreshTwitter
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];
    if (accountStore != nil)
    {
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore     accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
        if (accountType != nil)
        {
            [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (granted)
                 {
                     //Succesful Access
                     NSArray *twitterAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                     if (twitterAccounts != nil)
                     {
                         ACAccount *currentAccount = [twitterAccounts objectAtIndex:0];
                         if (currentAccount != nil)
                         {
                         NSString *requestString = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
                             SLRequest *request = [SLRequest     requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL     URLWithString:requestString] parameters:nil];
                             [request setAccount:currentAccount];

                             [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                             {
                                 if ((error == nil) && ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200))
                                 {
                                     NSArray *twitterFeed = [NSJSONSerialization     JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];

                                 // loop throught all posts

                                     for (NSInteger i=0; i<[twitterFeed count]; i++)
                                     {
                                         TwitterPostInfo *postInfo = [self     createPostInfoFromDictionary:[twitterFeed objectAtIndex:i]];

                                         if (postInfo != nil)
                                         {
                                             [twitterPosts addObject:postInfo];

                                         }
                                     }
                                 }
                             }];

                         }
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     //Access Denied
                 }
             }];
        }
    }

}

-(TwitterPostInfo*)createPostInfoFromDictionary:(NSDictionary*)postDictionary
    {


    NSString *timeDateString = [postDictionary valueForKey:@"created_at"];
    NSDictionary *userDictionary = [postDictionary objectForKey:@"user"];
    NSString *userString = [userDictionary valueForKey:@"screen_name"];
    NSString *userDesc = [userDictionary valueForKey:@"description"];
    NSString *tweetText = [postDictionary valueForKey:@"text"];

    TwitterPostInfo *postInfo = [[TwitterPostInfo alloc]initWithPostInfo:userString userDesc:userDesc text:tweetText timeDateInfo:timeDateString];

    return postInfo;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [twitterPosts count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CloneCell"];
    if (cell != nil)
    {
        // ISSUE BEGINS HERE

        //TwitterPostInfo *postInfo = (TwitterPostInfo*) twitterPosts[indexPath.row];
        //cell = [twitterPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [twitterPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    }
    return cell;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post about the valid cell object is important, but your real problem here is that you are assigning an object of type `TwitterPostInfo` to `cell.textLabel.text`, which is an `NSString`.

If what you're trying to display is the text of the Tweet, you'll want something more like this:

```
TwitterPostInfo *postInfo = (TwitterPostInfo*) twitterPosts[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = postInfo.text; //or however your getter for the text is implemented
```

If you're trying to display all of the information of the Tweet in the cell, you're going to have to create your own custom cell and then assign each UILabel in the cell to the different properties stored in the TwitterPostInfo object.

Comment: Thank You! This complimented the first answer!

Answer (score 0):

`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`  may return `nil`. In this case, you need to create a proper `UITableViewCell` yourself.

Try creating a cell if it is `nil`. Always make sure to return a valid cell object.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CloneCell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [twitterPosts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer! When you say "Create a proper UITableViewCell" you mean in storyboards?

Comment: @user3078406 That means this line: `cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
`.